# sfWidgetFormJQueryAutocompleter: how to retrieve the keys of the selected elements?

Tags: jquery, symfony1

i have this widget :

```
$this->widgetSchema['user']  = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
  'choices'          => array(),
  'renderer_class'   => 'sfWidgetFormJQueryAutocompleter',
  'renderer_options' => array('url' => 'autocomplete', 'config' => '{ multiple:true }'),
));
```

And this is the autocomplete function:

```
public function executeAutocomplete($request)
{

$this->getResponse()->setContentType('application/json');

$q = "%" . $request->getParameter('q') . "%";

$limit = $request->getParameter('limit');

//Criteria code

return $this->renderText(json_encode($cli));
```

}

that returns this ("Response" tab in Firebug):

```
{"17":"John","18":"Ann"}   //the numbers are the values in the id field.
```

Then i choose both names in the autocomplete input this way:

> [John, Peter]

When i submit the form, the getPostParameters() method returns this:

```
array
  'example' => 
    array
      'id' => string '' (length=0)
      '_csrf_token' => string '388774046d0f5c8b4a3f114ddb15af7b' (length=32)
      'user' => string '18' (length=2)
  'autocomplete_example' => 
    array
      'user' => string 'John, Ann, '
```

So what should i do to retrieve the id's of the users?

sf 1.4.

Javier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I understand how this widget works..When you create this kind
of widget, it actually creates two fields: autocomplete_my_field (the
field that is showed and where you insert the data (values of the
array elements) and my_field (a hidden field, where the keys are
inserted).

This widget works ok when you insert only an element but when you
insert more than an element the key of the elements are overwritten
(the id of the second element overwrites the id of the the first one,
the id of the third element overwrites the id of the second
one, ....), so you can not retrieve all them. So it's a bug I think..

EDIT:

maybe this snippet is usefull http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippets/from/antitoxic/order_by/popularity. In that snippet tags_list is not a casual name, is the name of the field generated by symfony that shows the elements of the other side of the relation. In that way you will overwrite it.